# Dynamic size with Autolayout in iOS 6

Tags: ios, autolayout

I would like to have a view having its size (in this case its height) dependent on the screen size to cover the screen of an iPhone4/iPhone6 with one xib. So lets say I take a ListView and I don't want to have it full screen but I have fixed spaces above and below. Its height should then be:

```
screen_height - (space_above + space_below)
```

In the Interface Builder I can set the two vertical space constraints and then even delete the height constraint of the ListView so its height is determined by the parent view and this two space constraints.

Having Freeform set in the simulated metrics I can drag to change the size of my root view and see the constraints working (the ListView resizes properly).

**The Problem:**

However, if I run the application in the simulator everything appears fixed as in the last position in the Interface Builder. What have I missed what prevents the layout to work according to its constraints?

If I change the simulated metrics to Retina 3.5 or 4, Xcode deletes my constraints and returns to the fixed size constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the root view which does not (other as assumed) take the size of the screen.

Perhaps not the best solution:

`[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];`

But it brings the view in the right size and let the constraints work.

Answer (score 0):

do you want this?

[image: autoLayout Portrait]

[image: autoLayout LandScape]

If yes, then magnify the images and follow the contraints from there. 
Its too interesting when you work with autoLayout, isn't it?